# What variable name should I pass to my function for sorting?

Tags: c++, function, vector, selection-sort

Edit: I realized that one of my problems was that I was trying to get my sorting function to sort a string, which obviously wouldn't work.

I need to sort data from a file that I organized into two vectors.  So I am using a function that will sort my data in the order I need, however, I can't figure out what variables I should have in the () of the call and of the function definition. I know I need to pass names and score in order for the function to sort it, but I don't know if I need to say (string name, int score) or (vector, vector

```
//Name
//This program will read and sort names and grades from a file using functions and vectors
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//Function prototype
void selectionSort(vector<int>& vector_values);

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("student.txt");

    if (infile.fail() == false)
    {
        vector<string> all_names;
        vector<int> all_scores;
        string name;
        int score;
        while (infile >> name >> score) // read one name and one score
        {
            all_names.push_back(name); // add that name to vector
            all_scores.push_back(score); // add that score to vector
            selectionSort();
            cout << name << " "<< score<<", ";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open the file." << endl;
    }
return 0;
}

void selectionSort(vector<int>& vector_values)
{
    for (unsigned pass = 0; pass < vector_values.size(); pass++)
    {
        int minimum = vector_values[pass];
        int minimum_index = pass;
        for (unsigned index = pass + 1; index < vector_values.size(); index++)
        {
            if (minimum > vector_values[index])
            {
                minimum = vector_values[index];
                minimum_index = index;
            }
        }

        int temp = vector_values[minimum_index];
        vector_values[minimum_index] = vector_values[pass];
        vector_values[pass] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `selectionSort()` is obviously wrong, you need to pass the vector you want to sort, for example `selectionSort(all_names)`. And you're calling `selectionSort()` in the wrong place, you should only call it once the file has been read. But anyway, the overall approache is wrong. You shouldn't have 2 vectors, but a single vector of a struct or a class that contains both name and score.

Comment: ... and you should use the sort functions of <algorithm> and not make your own sort functions, unless this is a requirement for an exercise.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't want to use two vectors, but it's the requirement for this lab

Comment: If you want to keep both vectors in sync, then my recommendation is that you learn about *structures* or *classes*, and create a *single* vector of your structure/class to sort.

Comment: And if it's a requirement to have two vectors and keep them in sync, you need to pass *both* vectors to your sorting function, and when you swap elements of one vector (the one you actually sorting on) you need to swap the corresponding elements from the other vector as well.

Comment: @yellogs for exercises, you should put all requirements into the question, otherwise you'll get comments like the one above.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ah, lesson learned haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read all the values first and then sort them after the loop.

The sort function is declared as:

```
void selectionSort(vector<int>& vector_values);
//                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

which means that it can accept an `std::vector<int>` by reference. So, with reference to your code, you need to pass `all_scores` because it is of the same type that is required by the sort function.

So, your code would look like this:

```
// Read values into the vectors
while (infile >> name >> score)
{
    all_names.push_back(name);
    all_scores.push_back(score);
}

// Values are populated, now sort here
selectionSort( all_scores );
```

---

If you are required to use an `std::vector` and also want to retain the relationship between the names and their associated scores, an alternative solution could be an `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>` or an `std::vector` of an aggregate type i.e. `struct` or `class`.

With two vectors' restrictions, you need to pass both to the sort function; and, swap names when you swap scores to retain their relationship.

For future reference, you might want to look at the associative containers such as [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to approach such problems.

Comment: Apparently the OP is required to maintain two different vectors, and obviously the relationship between the two vectors should be retained and I don't know how a map would help here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Thank you for your input! I've rephrased and updated the answer. The reference to `std::map` is a suggestion for the future.